# Let's eliminate the [region] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The [region](/questions/tagged/region) tag is used for a mixed bag of unrelated phenomena. It adds no information. I think it could be 'burned off'. Trogdor?

Comment: Some of those could go under i18n or l10n, depending on the context.  One or two of 'em, at least.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think the [region](/questions/tagged/region) tag should be burninated.

**However** it needs a little bit of cleanup first.

The definition for the tag is entirly unclear and the presense of the tag isn't providing a useful subset of topical questions. Overall it should be eliminated, however before it gets the wrath of trogdor there are a handful of qusetions that need to be properly tagged. The subset isn't too big, 286 questions need to be reviewed an any other appropriate tags added. Once any questions that need a proper tag in place of this one have been cleaned up, the remaining instances of the tag can be treated with fire.

For whoever does that review, consider adding [i18n](/questions/tagged/i18n) or [l10n](/questions/tagged/l10n) where appropriate.

Once that is done, another post back here to give an all clear would be in order.